# Controlling seperate call of VAST tag xml and prebuffer of next video ad in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, vast, google-ima

I am using jwplayer to play video ads from the VAST tag URL. 
jwplayer lets me do this using:

```
jwplayer("playerlive").playAd(tagurl);
```

This is good, if you just need play one ad. But i need to play multiple ads back to back and i am calling this function again and again. But because of this their is extra buffer screen that the user has to see, between the two ads.

Is their any way to avoid that by pre calling the tag XML and maybe even pre-buffering the next video ad that is coming.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: I don't mind the buffer screen at the start of ads and at the end. i just want to avoid the buffering in between the ads, for a seamless experience.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
jwplayer("playerlive").playAd(tagurl);
```

Why not use ad pods?

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1433722-ad-pods

Example set up code:

```
<div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    jwplayer("container").setup({    
        image: "http://demo.jwplayer.com.s3.amazonaws.com/advertising/assets/adpod.jpg",
        file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/s8BPzDe0-kNspJqnJ.mp4",
        width: 640,
        height: 360,
        advertising: {
            client:"vast",
            admessage:"This is an ad pod. This ad ends in xx seconds.",
            schedule:{
                adbreak1: {
                    offset:'pre',
                    tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/advertising/assets/vast3_jw_ads.xml'
                },

                overlay: {
                    offset:'5',
                    tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/advertising/assets/overlay.xml',
                    type:"nonlinear"
                },
                adbreak2: {
                    offset:'300',
                    tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/advertising/assets/vast3_jw_ads.xml'
                },
                adbreak3: {
                    offset:'post',
                    tag: 'http://demo.jwplayer.com/advertising/assets/vast3_jw_ads.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

For example, look at the ad tag for the preroll - http://demo.jwplayer.com/advertising/assets/vast3_jw_ads.xml

You can put in each vast tag into the XML file, so they all play together.

Comment: Thanks Ethan for the reply. I did looked this option and its a decent solution. But its limited by the number of ads delivered on a given adpod tag url. I actually don't know, in advance, that how many ads i am going to show . This actually depends on stream/content that i am showing. So if an adpod tag has 3 ads in it, which it can play back to back, but if require 5 ads to be played then i would have to make another call to a different adpod tag which had 2 ads in it, and their is again going to be a buffering screen between these 2 adpods.

I hope you understood the issue better. Thanks.

Comment: I see what you mean here. However, playAd() isn't really something that is meant to be chained back to back to back like this. It isn't really a tested solution.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Can you think of some way where i can do a pre-call to playAd() function, so that it can get the tag xml and maybe even prebuffer the ad video, but stop it from actually playing the ad right away, and play it at a later time. Thanks again.

Comment: It seems to be possible somehow. this DFP plugin for flowplayer seems to be suggesting that. Search for "smart ad preloading" on this page:
http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/advertising/dfp/index.html

Comment: There is no way to do a pre-call for playAd(). We have a plugin for us that uses DFP as well, called "googima", maybe you can look into using that?